# Export post data with xml to other site using php soap

Tags: php, api, xml, soap

At one non-wordpress site, I have to show dynamic posts (depends on chosen result), it`s thumbnail, header and short description. Before, I have to fetch these data from other wordpress site.

Can I do that with soap php api?

Please, do not recommend DOM parsing or plugins.

Comment: WordPress has json REST API

Comment: @birgire, Thank you bro.

Comment: Welcome ps: WordPress has native support for xml-rpc https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/handbook/xml-rpc/ and feeds (RSS, RSS2, Atom) but it's usually easier to just use the built-in REST API: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/